# calling sg.popup when SystemTray (psgtray) running

Tags: python, pysimplegui, system-tray

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from psgtray import SystemTray
import pyaudio 
import threading

def findAudioDevices():
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    info = p.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
    numdevices = info.get('deviceCount')
    device_info = ""
    for i in range(0, numdevices):
        if (p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('maxInputChannels')) > 0:
            device_info += f"Input Device ID {i} - {p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('name')}\n"
    sg.popup('Audio Devices', device_info)


# PySimpleGUI setup
menu_def = ['File', ['Show Audio Devices', 'Open Config', 'Exit']]
tooltip = 'Tooltip'

# Initialize the tray
tray = SystemTray(menu=menu_def, single_click_events=False, tooltip=tooltip, icon=r'Icon.png')
tray.show_message('Sound Switch', 'Sound Switchs Started!')

# Event loop
while True:
    menu_item = tray.key
    if menu_item == 'Exit':
        break
    elif menu_item == 'Show Audio Devices':
        findAudioDevices()  # This function should probably be modified to display a popup instead of printing to console
    elif menu_item == 'Open Config':
        os.system(f"notepad {config_path}")

tray.close()
```

leads to this error

```
An error occurred when calling message handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\willwade\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.4\Lib\site-packages\pystray\_win32.py", line 398, in _dispatcher
    return int(icon._message_handlers.get(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\willwade\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.4\Lib\site-packages\pystray\_win32.py", line 210, in _on_notify
    descriptors[index - 1](self)
  File "C:\Users\willwade\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.4\Lib\site-packages\pystray\_base.py", line 308, in inner
    callback(self)
  File "C:\Users\willwade\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.4\Lib\site-packages\pystray\_base.py", line 434, in __call__
    return self._action(icon, self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\willwade\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.11.4\Lib\site-packages\psgtray\psgtray.py", line 138, in _on_clicked
    self.window.write_event_value(self.key, item.text)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write_event_value'
```

So it looks like its ignoring sg and using psgtray - but I dont get it. I have a feeling its something to do with the window thread but I have no idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you removed the code for the hidden window, also no value for option `window` when initiate the `SystemTray`.

> The PySimpleGUI architecture implemented the tray icon using the psgtray package combined with the overall window event loop, a Window object is still required.

Revised code to

```py
import os
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from psgtray import SystemTray
import pyaudio
import threading

def findAudioDevices():
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    info = p.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
    numdevices = info.get('deviceCount')
    device_info = ""
    for i in range(0, numdevices):
        if (p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('maxInputChannels')) > 0:
            device_info += f"Input Device ID {i} - {p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('name')}\n"
    sg.popup('Audio Devices', device_info)


# PySimpleGUI setup
menu_def = ['File', ['Show Audio Devices', 'Open Config', 'Exit']]
tooltip = 'Tooltip'

layout = [[sg.T('Empty Window', key='-T-')]]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, finalize=True, enable_close_attempted_event=True, alpha_channel=0)
window.hide()

# Initialize the tray
tray = SystemTray(menu=menu_def, single_click_events=False, tooltip=tooltip, window=window)
tray.show_message('Sound Switch', 'Sound Switchs Started!')

# Event loop
while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    menu_item = values[event]

    if menu_item == 'Exit':
        break
    elif menu_item == 'Show Audio Devices':
        findAudioDevices()  # This function should probably be modified to display a popup instead of printing to console
    elif menu_item == 'Open Config':
        sg.popup(menu_item)
        # os.system(f"notepad {config_path}")

tray.close()
window.close()
```